# Formatando gráfico de colunas do Google Chart

Tags: javascript, chart

Estou precisando realizar dois ajustes em um gráfico criado com a ferramenta Google Charts.

O primeiro deles se diz respeito à formatação do vAxis para a moeda no formato brasileiro.
Consegui configurar o prefixo R$, contudo não entendi como faz a formatação dos símbolos (ponto final e vírgula). ex: **R$ 1,200.50** para **R$ 1.200,50**.

```
 vAxis: {
      format: 'R$ #,##0.00',
      title: ''
    },
```

Obs: a documentação do Google Chart é bem incompleta a respeito deste aspecto. Eles dão um exemplo mostrando apenas o uso do separador **'#,###'**, porém, não há informações apresentado como trocar este separador.

E o segundo ajuste que preciso alterar é o tamanho da fonte dos valores que são apresentados dentro do gráfico. (Obs: esses valores já consegui formatar com a moeda brasileira, de acordo com o seguinte código:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ prefix: 'R$ ', decimalSymbol: ',', groupingSymbol: '.' }); formatter.format(data, 0); formatter.format(data, 1);
```

Segue o print:
[image: Print do gráfico]

Procurei bastante na documentação do Google Chart, fiz pesquisas no Google, e de fato não encontrei nenhuma informação para estas minhas dúvidas.
Obrigado desde já quem puder me ajudar!

Comment: não tem ai no seu código, mas configurou o "locale" e "language"? a formatação numérica deve ser aplicada automaticamente se estiver bem configurado

Comment: Top demais, meu amigo! deu certo... Como faço para adicionar o seu comentário como resposta? Muito obrigado =D

Comment: adicionei uma resposta com o que foi comentado :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguindo a documentação do Google Chart aqui: [loadwithlocale](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#loadwithlocale)

É preciso setar o language, assim por exemplo:

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart'],
  language: 'pt-BR'
});
```